# Are there categorifications of prime or irreducible elements (of a ring, say)?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, soft-question, categorification

There's a categorification of what it means to be an element of a set; indeed, from Goldblatt's [*Topoi: The Categorial Analysis of Logic*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Topoi-Categorial-Analysis-Logic-Mathematics/dp/0486450260), we have this

> **Definition:** In any category $\mathbb{C}$ with terminal object $1_{\mathbb{C}}$, an *element* of a $\mathbb{C}$-object $a$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-arrow $1_{\mathbb{C}}\stackrel{x}{\to}a$.

The idea of [categorification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorification) is, that of replacing sets with categories, elements with objects, relations between elements with morphisms between objects, etc., so perhaps the above isn't *quite* a categorification of an element.

There's the category of rings and ring homomorphisms.

> So are there categorifications of the notions of [prime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeElement.html) or [irreducible](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreducibleElement.html) elements (of a ring, say)?

Comment: This is not so much categorification as it is rephrasing in category-theoretic language.

Comment: Agreed, that's not a categorification. A categorification should tell you what a "categorified element" of a "categorified set" is. (There's a silly answer here, which is that a "categorified set" is a category and a "categorified element" is an object. Categorification is not always so useful.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you. Does this warrant me rewording the question? I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object $X$ of a category is called *[indecomposable](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indecomposable+object)* if $X$ not initial and for every coproduct decomposition $X = A \oplus B$ we have that either $A$ or $B$ is initial. Similarly, $X$ is called [simple](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simple+object) (or *irreducible*) if $X$ has exactly two quotients. Both notions are very common in representation theory. In [Krull-Schmidt categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_category) we have categorified prime factorizations.

Comment: *Wow*. So, why the coproduct and not the product? :)

Comment: I've also seen it with a product. These notions are just dual to each other.

Comment: Ah, I figured as much. Thank you :)